# Can you logically replicate a physical Postgres replica?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-12

The title is pretty much self-explanatory. To illustrate more, here's a picture:

`[Live Database]-->(physical replication)-->[Physical Replica]-->(logical replication)-->[Logical Replica]`

So the question is whether this setup is achievable? All the databases involved are PostgreSQL 12 instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, because that would mean creating a logical replication slot on the physical standby. Attempting to create such a replication slot would lead to this error:

```
ERROR:  logical decoding cannot be used while in recovery
```

Comment: Can you create the publication on the primary and so that it would get replicated to the secondary? And then have the subscriber connect to the replica?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A justified question. I have verified that it does not work and improved the answer.